# All External Drives Mounted as Read only Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: usb, mount, automount

Whenever I try to mount drives via any file manager they only mount as read only even if I run the file manager as root. Appears to affect all drive types.

Answer (score 0):

This could be with Windows dual boot, specifically 'Windows Fast Startup.'  For some reason this highjacks all external devices.  Follow [THIS](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) tutorial to turn it off, but be warned, windows likes to turn it back on every few updates.  Give this a bookmark for later.

Hope this helps!